# How to choose the wanted root of the maximum likelihood function when there are multiple roots?

Tags: likelihood, extreme-value

I need to estimate a parameter of a distribution but I don't have an explicit estimator. I decided to do a partition of the interval range for the parameter and use the newton-raphson method to find roots of the ML function. In simulated data, I am getting 2 distinct roots. How to find the "right" one? In fact, looking at the highest obtained value for the ML, the "best" root is the wrong one. So, I can´t use the maximum likelihood value as a criterion to choose. Increasing the sampling size the "wrong" root disappears remaining only the "right" root with a smaller error. This result is in agreement with the stabilished theory. My question is: how to identify the "right" root for small sample sizes?

Comment: How do you define “best” and how can you tell it’s wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be finding roots: you should be finding *optima.*  If you're looking for roots, then you are likely finding roots of the *derivative* of the likelihood as a preliminary method for identifying *some* of the possible optima.  There can be multiple solutions *only* when the likelihoods associated with all of them are equal.  Is that the case in your application?

Comment: it may be useful to impose some smoothing via a prior distribution (that is, do do MAP rather than MLE).

Comment: I am estimating on simulated data so, I know before hand what is the true parameter value I should get.

Comment: The procedure is: I build a partition for the parameter range [a_0,a_1]. Next, I use each partition value as a starting point for the Newton-Raphson scheme. If consecutive values of the parameter are close enough I consider that the process has converged and I calculate the Likelihood for that value. In the end, I have a list of estimated parameter values. I select the subinterval containing the point with highest likelihood,  [a_i a_{i+1}], and I make a_0=a_i, a_1=a_{i+1} and the process starts all over again. The algorithm stops when |a_1-a_0| is smaller than a pre-defined value

Comment: The algorithm isn't complete until you have evaluated the optimal likelihood within each interval and selected *only* those arguments attaining that optimum.

Comment: I select the the parameter estimate corresponding to the highest likelihood value but it is a numerical calculation which is subjected to error. That is the difficulty when choosing the root corresponding to the correct estimate. In simulation I detected cases where the root with highest likelihood does not correspond to the parameter value used to generate the data.

Comment: The histogram of the estimated parameter is bi-modal and when plotting likelihood against estimate I get two distinct and separated clouds of points.

Comment: 1. Given that you are estimating the parameter, of course the maximum likelihood estimate won't equal the true parameter.  2. If you are having numerical issues evaluating the likelihood function, how big are they?  Do you work directly with the log of the likelihood function or the likelihood function itself?  If the latter, try the former.

Comment: That can happen.  It's a problem, but not an error.  You choose the best root you can find and sometimes it will be (very) wrong.  This is especially a risk with small datasets, where there are no assurances MLE will be any good at all.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. Since I am looking for the maximum I should check if the second derivative is positive. I have done that and know it works well. But I agree with you, for small data sets the error can be huge...

Comment: You don't need to check the second derivative and it won't suffice anyway.  All you need to do is find the largest of the values of the likelihoods at your candidate solutions.

Comment: I am working with the log likelihood. I think I don't have numerical problems other that the limitations of the Newton-Raphson method. I've eliminated the estimates with positive 2nd log likelihood derivative. Even so, two clouds of point still exist in the  log-likelihood against estimate plot. I increased the size of data by a factor of 20 so that convergence to a unique root could occur.

Comment: The wrong maxima still appears but not with the highest loglikelihood and with much less estimates pointing to that root. On the other hand the estimates for the correct root are much more precise as expected.

Comment: Hello again. Using in simulation different values of the parameter I want to estimate and with a reasonable size of data I am getting the wrong estimate choosing the best to be the one with highest loglikelihood. I am also getting plots logL vs estimate and estimate vs D2logL hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

The theory and application of identifying estimators from multiple roots of estimating equations (including the case of maximum likelihood estimation) is discussed in a relatively new book that I have authored : See
Brenton R. Clarke (2018) Robustness Theory and Application, John Wiley & Sons, Hoboken New Jersey.  See in particular Chapter 4.

Reading the first three chapters requires a bit of mathematics understanding but is recommended.   Also note the idea of a selection functional.

Brenton

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/354474)